# Select dropdown for dynamic array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
<ol class="noDots"> 
  <% @film.screenings.each do |s| %>
    <li> 
      <h3><%= link_to s.cinema.name, s.cinema %></h3>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Hi everyone,

I want to put this function in a dropdown menu, i have researched and it led me to nowhere.

[Ruby on Rails form select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501199/ruby-on-rails-form-select)

I tried this but this also didnt work.

Any help would be good!

Thanks in advance

**EDIT SOLVED**

Ok so i read the API documentation,

```
 <%= select_tag("random", options_from_collection_for_select(@film.cinemas, "id", "name"), {:prompt => "Pick a cinema...", :onchange => "window.open('/cinemas/' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')"}) %>
```

and it worked :)

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you trying to do? The code that you have and the link that you had posted have little relation to each other. Are you trying to make a form with a select box which includes dynamic values?

Comment: im trying to create a select box with the name s.cinema.name and linking to s.cinema. When you click on the s.cinema.name it takes you to s.cinema and this is done through a loop.

Comment: OK just to be clear you have a model `Cinema` that `belongs_to :screenings` which `belongs_to :films`, right?

Comment: `Cinema` `has_many :screenings` `has_many :films, :through => :screenings` -   `Film` `has_many :screenings` - `Screening` `belongs_to :cinema` `belongs_to :film`

Comment: This should be done with either css or javascript. and not rails

Comment: Read the original post please, i have updated

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with rails; just load into into a [select tag](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/select/).