# How to add placeholder for drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want placeholder text (predefined one "Select any status") for my drop down menu.The following is my code for drop down menu

```
<%= f.select :status,[[],['Created','Created'],['Deleted','Deleted'],
['Modified','Modified'],['Stored','Stored'],['Trained/Broken','Trained/Broken'],
['Unnecessary','Unnecessary']] %>
```

Ruby:1.9.3
Rails 3.2.13

Thanks in advance

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501199/ruby-on-rails-form-select

Comment: <%= f.select  :status,[['Select Status',nil],['Created','Created'],['Deleted','Deleted'],['Modified','Modified'],['Stored','Stored'],['Trained/Broken','Trained/Broken'],['Unnecessary','Unnecessary']],:required => true %> required is not working when field is empty also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`prompt`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) for this:

```
<%= f.select :status,[[],['Created','Created'],['Deleted','Deleted'],
['Modified','Modified'],['Stored','Stored'],['Trained/Broken','Trained/Broken'],
['Unnecessary','Unnecessary']], prompt: "Please Select" %>
```

Comment: Thankz!! Rich Peck, its working fine . I want this field as 
:required:true one.If user doesn't fill this field it should prompt message like "You should fill it"